# Why does my spout in Apache storm sleep a lot?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm profiling my storm topology and noticed that main thread that does tuple processing and emitting sleeps a lot. Is this normal in Storm?
Example in VisualVM below are the stats

[image: Visial VM sample time spent during ~31Mins of run]

Also if this is normal. How can it be tweaked?

Comment: For some reason the screen shot doesn't upload however around 3776759 milliseconds the thread is sleeping in this method during a sample run of 31 mins

Comment: It depends on you load. For example, if Spout#next() is called, but does not emit any data, Storm applies a sleep strategy to avoid busy waiting on the spout thread.

Comment: See "Spout wait strategy" http://storm.apache.org/2012/09/06/storm081-released.html

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates that bolts are comparatively slower and not acknowledging the tuples in time. Storm doesn't emit more tuples if the number of unacknowledged tuples crosses the configured threshold.

If you don't think that is the scenario, you can try increasing the max spout pending for your spout as well as increasing the queue size.